# How to submit app without In-App Purchases

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to make a bundle identifier that doesn't require me to submit IAPs. For the explicit id, I can't find where to turn it off or uncheck the box. I noticed that I can make a wild card id, but *Game Center* is disabled and I want to have *Game Center*.

So, can we submit an identifier with IAPs enabled but not use any IAPs?

Comment: At the moment you decide to create a wildcard ID, GameCenter will be disabled by default without an option to activate it. You need an explicit ID for this.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, as  Game Center and In-App Purchase are enabled by default for an explicit iOS App ID and can't be disabled.

Having them enabled, though, does not mean that you are forced to use them nor means that you are actively using them.